How to define groups in `plotnine` using interactions of features
I cannot find how to do the equivalent of ggplot's interaction feature.
What I'd like to do
This site has an example that has the sort of thing I am looking to reproduce: I have two discrete factors (in the example, store and promotion), and I would like to produce a line plot with each unique combination making a "group" to connect the lines with.
Example in ggplot
Taking it from the example above:
#create line plot with values grouped by store and promo
ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=sales, color=store, shape=promo,
               group=interaction(store, promo))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line()

What I'd expect to work in plotnine
import plotnine as p9
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'week': [1,2,3,4]*4,
    'store': (["A"]*8 + ["B"]*8),
    'promo': (["promo1"]*4 + ["promo2"]*4)*2,
    'sales': [1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 8, 9]
})

#create line plot with values grouped by store and promo
(
  p9.ggplot(df, p9.aes(x="week", y="sales", color="store", shape="promo",
               group="interaction(store, promo)")) + 
  p9.geom_point(size=3) +
  p9.geom_line()
)

This breaks because it doesn't know what interaction is. If I want the plot, I have to create a column in the data solely for defininte groups:
# ... as before

df['group_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row.store, row.promo), axis=1)
(
  p9.ggplot(df, p9.aes(x="week", y="sales", color="store", shape="promo",
               group="group_col")) + 
  p9.geom_point(size=3) +
  p9.geom_line()
)

This isn't great, because it means I am manually creating (and the tidying columns) for every plot grouping that makes sense, rather than the R-style approach where the interaction happens inside p9 but doesn't alter the actual data frame.
Addendum for interaction comment
An answer below stated I wanted to use interaction which was a R feature, and wasn't in Python (and thus wasn't part of a plotnine question). That wasn't what was being asked for; in the expectation section I was expecting to use interaction in a similar way I use factor.
In more detail: The expectation part didn't expect to use interaction as a function, it was part of string interpolation:
       .... group="interaction(store, promo)"))

The python interpreter never sees a call to interaction, it only sees a string. This is similar to how factor works in plotnine -- factor is a base R function, but we can use
       .... color="factor(numeric_id)"

in a plotnine geom, and it will interpret the numeric_id as a discrete variable, rather than a continuous one.

As week is a numeric adding a group aes isn't necessary. For this reason I slightly modified the example data by making week a character so that we end up with an example where both ggplot2 and plotnine require to explicitly map on the group aes to get a line .
Based on the modified example a possible workaround or an alternative to the use of interaction which I use quite often in ggplot2 is to concatenate the columns, i.e. in R I would do group = paste(store, promo, sep = ".") and in plotnine we can do group="store + '.' + promo" (Actually adding a separator is not required but I made it a habit to add it to resemble the output of interaction).
import plotnine as p9
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'week': ['1', '2', '3', '4']*4,
    'store': (["A"]*8 + ["B"]*8),
    'promo': (["promo1"]*4 + ["promo2"]*4)*2,
    'sales': [1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 8, 9]
})

#create line plot with values grouped by store and promo
(
  p9.ggplot(df, p9.aes(x="week", y="sales", color="store", shape="promo",
            group="store + '.' + promo")) + 
  p9.geom_point(size=3) +
  p9.geom_line()
)



Sorry for the verbosity of this response, but I think there's two separate questions here.
Create the same plot w/ plotnine
Unless I'm missing something, I don't think adding a group to aesthetics added anything to the plot.
Using ggplot2
Below is the R code you referenced:
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(store=rep(c('A', 'B'), each=8),
                 promo=rep(c('Promo 1', 'Promo 2'), each=4, times=2),
                 week=rep(c(1:4), times=4),
                 sales=c(1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 8, 9))

# With Interaction
ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=sales, color=store, shape=promo,
               group=interaction(store, promo))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line()



# Without Interaction
ggplot(df, aes(x=week, y=sales, color=store, shape=promo)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line()


Created on 2024-09-11 with reprex v2.1.1
Using plotnine
Just remove the group from your plotnine call:
import plotnine as p9
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'week': [1,2,3,4]*4,
    'store': (["A"]*8 + ["B"]*8),
    'promo': (["promo1"]*4 + ["promo2"]*4)*2,
    'sales': [1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 3, 5, 8, 9]
})

#create line plot with values grouped by store and promo
(
  p9.ggplot(df, p9.aes(x="week", y="sales", color="store", shape="promo")) + 
  p9.geom_point(size=3) +
  p9.geom_line()
)


Using interaction() in python
You say interaction doesn't work in plotnine.interaction() is a function in base R. It's not a part of ggplot2. You're calling it in a python environment, but it's not a function in python that you can reference.
If you want to create interaction terms in python, here's a useful reference for doing so.

Hi Mark, for the "use interaction in python" comment at the end: look at how I anticipate being able to use it. I have it in a string interpolation: group="interaction(store, promo)". The same comment could be made for factor, but it is useful and plotnine does make factor available for string interpolation -- you don't have to define your numeric categories as categorical and then jump into plotnine, you can pass (for example) color="factor(store_id)", and end up with a discrete color scale, even if the store_id is numeric.

I do appreciate you pointing out the group isn't necessary in this case (between color and shape, they define the groups for lines). This wasn't my actual problem, my problem was trying to look at thousands of SKUs where I don't want labels for each or differentiation between the SKUs, but I want to connect the pre- and post- behaviors of the SKUs (similar to https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-visualize-longitudinal-data-in-ggplot2/). Your point is good -- I chose a poor minimal example for the problem I was having!

Gotcha I didn't realize you could use factor() in plotnine aesthetics (good to know!) so I get your confusion. In fairness though, that's a super common use case to need to convert numeric data to categories that base python doesn't have a really simple way to handle afaik... You could probably add one to plotnine, but I'm not super familiar with the internals. I see where they implement factor here - https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/blob/4159f9548fa5f95c02366efc324e88f9ba79af09/plotnine/layer.py#L253-L271
